# Receive private facebook message via website?

Tags: php, facebook

I have similar questions but not really answered.

Is there a way my customers on our website can send a private facebook message from my website to my personal facebook profile?

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/):

> You can integrate Facebook Chat into your Web-based, desktop, or mobile instant messaging products. Your instant messaging client connects to Facebook Chat via the Jabber/XMPP service.

Comment: And on the top of the page it say: "The service and API this document covers has been deprecated with the release of Platform API v2.0. Once version 1.0 is deprecated, chat.facebook.com will no longer be available."